# Mysql query/count in php help- count number of occurencies distinct to ID's

Tags: php, mysql, counting

Let's say we have two tables:

```
users
id     login     password
1      user1     $432rget5343
2      user2     $432rget5343
3      user3     $432rget5343


trips
id     date         driver_id      passengers
1      19-05-2016   1              [2][3]
2      19-05-2016   2              [1][3]
3      19-05-2016   1              [2][3]
4      19-05-2016   1              [2]
```

Basically the goal of the whole script is to keep track of driving to work in a group of a few people. Every day someone else is driving (driver_id)
and I need to somehow calculate who should drive next.
Above are the tables I've come up with, most of the script is already done, but I got stuck at counting this.

From above tables the desired output should be:

1. driver id 1 drove with passengers 2 and 3 therefore people with id 2 and 3 owe "1" to the one with id of 1
2. Guy with ID 2 drove this time, therefore his counter towards guy with ID 1 is now zero, and passenger three now "owes" +1 for id-1 and +1 for id-2
3. id 1 is a driver again, so now id 2 has +1 for id 1 and guy with id of 3 now "owes" +2 for the driver with id 1
4. 1 is the driver again, but he only takes one passenger, therefore guy with id of 2 now "owes" +2 for id of 1

I hope that my explanation is clear. Sorry you had to read that much.
Data is literally the same as in the dumps above (with square brackets etc.)

Any idea how to do this the right way?

Comment: Sounds like a class assignment. Have you tried anything yet? I would structure the tables differently.

Comment: At the moment it is about thinking on how to do it. How would you change table structure?

Comment: Separate the data so the table is normalized, 1 row per value.

Comment: You mean split passengers to like passengers1 passengers2 passengers3 passengers4?
I don't think that's a good solution as every trip there is a different number of passengers.

Comment: One row per passenger, separate passengers and trip. Trip has unique identifier, that associated the passengers with the trips.

Comment: Also the number of users might change so this would mess it up and I would need to modify db structure with every new user. That's how I understand it, am I correct?

Comment: No, because there is one row per rider so you can have infinite number of rows/riders.

Comment: I don't quite get it, could you please show me an example?

Comment: Rough extrapolation: Set up `trips`, `riders`, and `rides` as tables. `Trip` auto incrementents, you use that id on rides and you associate the ride to the trip.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can't change the database structure and that you are using MySQL, then you can do this:

```
// Set up the connection to the database
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASS, DBNAME);

// Execute the query
$results = $mysqli->query('SELECT driver_id, passengers FROM trips');

// Here we store all trips records
$records = [];

// Loop through all results
while($row = $results->fetch_array())
{
    $driver_id = $row[0];

    // If the driver id is not in the records, we add it
    if(!array_key_exists($driver_id, $records))
    {
        $records[$driver_id] = [];
    }

    // We parse the passenger string and retrieve an array with the ids
    $passengers = explode('[', substr(str_replace(']', '', $row[1]), 1));

    // We check every passenger
    foreach ($passengers as $passenger) {

        $passenger_id = intval($passenger);

        // As the driver drove the passenger, he owes -1 to him
        $records[$driver_id][$passenger_id]--;

        // If the passenger's id is not in the records, we add it
        if(!array_key_exists($passenger_id, $records))
        {
            $records[$passenger_id] = [];
        }

        // We update the passenger debt towards the driver
        $records[$passenger_id][$driver_id]++;
    }

}

foreach($records as $id => $record)
{
    foreach($record as $other_id => $iou)
    {
        // We are only interested in positive values
        if ($iou > 0)
            echo "Driver #$id owes driver #$other_id $iou trip(s)</br>";
    }
}
```

This will give you the following output:

```
Driver #2 owes driver #1 2 trip(s)
Driver #3 owes driver #1 2 trip(s)
Driver #3 owes driver #2 1 trip(s)
```